# Android: Layout for overlapping events in calendar

Tags: dynamic, android-layout, calendar, overlapping

I'm currently working on a calendar app. When the user selects the Day View, he needs to get a view similar to this example:

http://postimage.org/image/2sboxa22s/

I'm not really sure how to do this as the layout must be created at runtime because the number of events, their duration, how many are overlapping etc. is variable.

I've tried to find similar problems with no success.

My own two cents would be something like using a FrameLayout with a LinearLayout for the background (yellow with grey lines) and another FrameLayout on top of that in which the events would be placed. Only problem with this is that I'm not sure how to get the placement right nor how to figure out how to handle the places where events overlap.

**UPDATE**

Since there is no such thing as rowspan in the Android-framework (it is simply not supported by any layout or widget) I had to come up with my own solution.

In short terms I do the following:

1. Add a spacer (empty calendar) until I reach the start of the first appointment.
2. Add first appointment to a list and then add all appointments that overlaps any one appointment in the list to the list.
3. When there are no more overlapping appointments its time to add the list to the calendar.
4. I run through the appointments again to determine which can be in the same column and which cannot.
5. Add the required number of columns filling empty space between appointments with empty layouts.
6. Repeat untill all appointments of the day are added.

This solution builds on one thing: Fixed minimum height. This means I have a minimum height that an appointment must have. In my case its 60dp. I then find the shortest appointment to figure out a factor from which I can calculate the height of each appointment. E.g. if the shortest appointment i 15 minutes the factor would be 4.

This way an appointment in a column where the shortet appointment is 15 minutes, a 15 minutes long appointment would be 60dp and a 1 hour long appointment would be 240dp.

I don't consider this an optimal solution as it is not 100% dynamical, but it gets the job done so far.

Comment: I can't understand why everyone as to reinvent the wheel.
Of course most project aren't really open-source but this might be the 1000th calendar app...

Comment: Even if this was calendar app nr. 1000 - the ones that are availible do not meet the requirements of the company I'm developing for. Hence I need to build the whole app myself. This question is just as much a question about achieving true rowspan as that feature is not availible in the android framework.

Answer (score 2):

I have deeply looked into your issue however i found there are few problem with your layout design you must generate events through a class which identifies views and place them accordingly without overlapping any other event

http://postimg.org/image/4lqmlnhk7/ (Output for Reference)

```
private int[] Gettimespan(int SHour, int EHour, int SMinutes, int EMinutes, int TotalWidth) {
    // float x = (60 / Minutes) * 100;
    int x = 0; // width for time marking
    int y = 0; // Height For hour marking
    int z = 0; // Margin left for Stime
    int YAxis = 0; // YAxis Adjustment

    int TotalYAxis = 80; // /Total YAxis of Per hour slot
    int HalfOf_TotalYAxis = 40; // /Half of the Total YAxis of Per hour slot
    int MinutesDiff = GetMinutes(SHour, EHour, SMinutes, EMinutes);



    int xAxisFinetuning = 0;
    //Check If any Views Between
    final RelativeLayout rl = (RelativeLayout) _activity.findViewById(R.id.relativeLayout4);
    List<Integer> ViewCount = DetectView(SHour, rl);
    if(ViewCount.size() > 1 && ViewCount != null)
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < ViewCount.size(); i++)
        {
            LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout) _activity.findViewById(ViewCount.get(i));
            int Stepper = TotalWidth / ViewCount.size();
            xAxisFinetuning += Stepper;
            z  = xAxisFinetuning;
            ll.setMinimumWidth(Stepper - 15);
            ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams p = (ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams) ll.getLayoutParams();
            p.leftMargin = z;
            ll.requestLayout();
            x = Stepper - 26;
            //Log.d("LayoutID", "" + ll.getId());
        }
    }

    //Snippet 1: Case Same hour but upper span
    //if(SMinutes >= 0 && EMinutes >= 30 && SMinutes <= 30 && ((SHour+1 == EHour) || (SHour == EHour)))
    if(SMinutes >= 0 && EMinutes >= 30 && SMinutes <= 30 && (SHour == EHour))
    {
        if(x == 0)
        {
            x = TotalWidth;
        }

        if(y == 0)
        {
            if(MinutesDiff > 30)
            {
                y = dpToPx(TotalYAxis); 
            }
            else
            {
                y = dpToPx(HalfOf_TotalYAxis);  
            }
        }
        //if(z == 0)
        //{
        z = 0;
        //}
        if(MinutesDiff >= 30)
        {
            YAxis = 0;  
        }
        else
        {
            YAxis = HalfOf_TotalYAxis;
        }

        return new int[] { x, y - 6, z, YAxis };
    }

    // End Snippet 1.

    //Snippet 2: Case Same hour but lower span
    //if(SMinutes >= 30 && ((SHour+1 == EHour) || (SHour == EHour)))
    if(SMinutes >= 30 && (SHour == EHour))
    {
        if(x == 0)
        {
            x = TotalWidth;
        }

        if(y == 0)
        {
            if(MinutesDiff > 30)
            {
                y = dpToPx(TotalYAxis); 
            }
            else
            {
                y = dpToPx(HalfOf_TotalYAxis);  
            }
        }

        z = 0;

        if(MinutesDiff > 30)
        {
            YAxis = 0;  
        }
        else
        {
            YAxis = HalfOf_TotalYAxis;
        }


        return new int[] { x, y - 6, z, YAxis };
    }

    // End Snippet 2.

    //Snippet 3: Case when Total Hour > 1

    if(SHour != EHour )
    {
        if(x == 0)
        {
        x = TotalWidth;
        }
        if(y == 0)
        {
            Log.d("Calendar Case Next Day", "Ehour " + EHour + " Shour " + SHour);
            if((EHour - SHour)<=1)
            {
            y = dpToPx(((EHour - SHour)+1) * TotalYAxis);
            }
            else
            {
                y = dpToPx(((EHour - SHour)) * TotalYAxis);
            }
        }
        z = 0;
        YAxis = 0;

        return new int[] { x, y - 6, z, YAxis };
    }

    // End Snippet 3.


    return new int[] { x, y - 6, z, YAxis };
    }

private void TimeSpanning(LinearLayout LL, int SHour, int EHour, int SMinutes, int EMinutes, int TotalWidth, TextView Tv) {

    if(SHour > EHour)
    {
        Log.d("Calendar Case Next Day_", "Ehour " + EHour + " Shour " + SHour + " TextView " + Tv.getText());
        EHour = 24;
        //EMinutes = 59;
    }

    int minuteAdjustment = 0;

    if((EHour + ":" + EMinutes).equalsIgnoreCase(SHour + ":" + SMinutes))
    {
        //Log.d("EqualFound","True");
        minuteAdjustment = 59;
    }

    int[] x = Gettimespan(SHour, EHour, SMinutes, EMinutes + minuteAdjustment, TotalWidth);

    //Log.d("Eminute"," - " + EMinutes);

    LL.setMinimumWidth(x[0]);
    LL.setMinimumHeight(x[1]);

    Tv.setWidth(x[0]);
    Tv.setHeight(x[1] - 14);

    int Padding_Top_Bottom = 4;
    int Padding_Left_Right = 4;
    //LL.setPadding(30, 30, 30, 30);
    //tv.setWidth(x[0]);
    //tv.setHeight(x[1]);

    ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams p = (ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams) LL.getLayoutParams();
    //ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams p1 = (ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams) ll.getLayoutParams();

    switch (SHour) {
    case 0: {
        // 12 am
        p.setMargins(x[2] + Padding_Left_Right, dpToPx(GetCalendarScaleY(0) + x[3]) + Padding_Top_Bottom, Padding_Left_Right, 0);
        LL.requestLayout();
        break;
    }

    case 1: {
        // 1 am
        p.setMargins(x[2] + Padding_Left_Right, dpToPx(GetCalendarScaleY(1) + x[3]) + Padding_Top_Bottom, Padding_Left_Right, 0);
        LL.requestLayout();
        break;
    }

    case 2: {
        // 2 am
        p.setMargins(x[2] + Padding_Left_Right, dpToPx(GetCalendarScaleY(2) + x[3]) + Padding_Top_Bottom, Padding_Left_Right, 0);
        LL.requestLayout();
        break;
    }

    case 3: {
        // 3 am
        p.setMargins(x[2] + Padding_Left_Right, dpToPx(GetCalendarScaleY(3) + x[3]) + Padding_Top_Bottom, Padding_Left_Right, 0);
        LL.requestLayout();
        break;
    }

    case 4: {
        // 4 am
        p.setMargins(x[2] + Padding_Left_Right, dpToPx(GetCalendarScaleY(4) + x[3]) + Padding_Top_Bottom, Padding_Left_Right, 0);
        LL.requestLayout();
        break;
    }

    case 5: {
        // 5 am
        p.setMargins(x[2] + Padding_Left_Right, dpToPx(GetCalendarScaleY(5) + x[3]) + Padding_Top_Bottom, Padding_Left_Right, 0);
        LL.requestLayout();
        break;
    }

    case 6: {
        // 6 am
        p.setMargins(x[2] + Padding_Left_Right, dpToPx(GetCalendarScaleY(6) + x[3]) + Padding_Top_Bottom, Padding_Left_Right, 0);
        LL.requestLayout();
        break;
    }

    case 7: {
        // 7 am
        p.setMargins(x[2] + Padding_Left_Right, dpToPx(GetCalendarScaleY(7) + x[3]) + Padding_Top_Bottom, Padding_Left_Right, 0);
        LL.requestLayout();
        break;
    }

    case 8: {
        // 8 am
        p.setMargins(x[2] + Padding_Left_Right, dpToPx(GetCalendarScaleY(8) + x[3]) + Padding_Top_Bottom, Padding_Left_Right, 0);
        LL.requestLayout();
        break;
    }

    case 9: {
        // 9 am
        p.setMargins(x[2] + Padding_Left_Right, dpToPx(GetCalendarScaleY(9) + x[3]) + Padding_Top_Bottom, Padding_Left_Right, 0);
        LL.requestLayout();
        break;
    }

    case 10: {
        // 10 am
        p.setMargins(x[2] + Padding_Left_Right, dpToPx(GetCalendarScaleY(10) + x[3]) + Padding_Top_Bottom, Padding_Left_Right, 0);
        LL.requestLayout();
        break;
    }

    case 11: {
        // 11 am
        p.setMargins(x[2] + Padding_Left_Right, dpToPx(GetCalendarScaleY(11) + x[3]) + Padding_Top_Bottom, Padding_Left_Right, 0);
        LL.requestLayout();
        break;
    }

    case 12: {
        // 12 pm
        p.setMargins(x[2] + Padding_Left_Right, dpToPx(GetCalendarScaleY(12) + x[3]) + Padding_Top_Bottom, Padding_Left_Right, 0);
        LL.requestLayout();
        break;
    }

    case 13: {
        // 1 pm
        p.setMargins(x[2] + Padding_Left_Right, dpToPx(GetCalendarScaleY(13) + x[3]) + Padding_Top_Bottom, Padding_Left_Right, 0);
        LL.requestLayout();
        break;
    }

    case 14: {
        // 2 pm
        p.setMargins(x[2] + Padding_Left_Right, dpToPx(GetCalendarScaleY(14) + x[3]) + Padding_Top_Bottom, Padding_Left_Right, 0);
        LL.requestLayout();
        break;
    }

    case 15: {
        // 3 pm
        p.setMargins(x[2] + Padding_Left_Right, dpToPx(GetCalendarScaleY(15) + x[3]) + Padding_Top_Bottom, Padding_Left_Right, 0);
        LL.requestLayout();
        break;
    }

    case 16: {
        // 4 pm
        p.setMargins(x[2] + Padding_Left_Right, dpToPx(GetCalendarScaleY(16) + x[3]) + Padding_Top_Bottom, Padding_Left_Right, 0);
        LL.requestLayout();
        break;
    }

    case 17: {
        // 5 pm
        p.setMargins(x[2] + Padding_Left_Right, dpToPx(GetCalendarScaleY(17) + x[3]) + Padding_Top_Bottom, Padding_Left_Right, 0);
        LL.requestLayout();
        break;
    }

    case 18: {
        // 6 pm
        p.setMargins(x[2] + Padding_Left_Right, dpToPx(GetCalendarScaleY(18) + x[3]) + Padding_Top_Bottom, Padding_Left_Right, 0);
        LL.requestLayout();
        break;

    }

    case 19: {
        // 7 pm
        p.setMargins(x[2] + Padding_Left_Right, dpToPx(GetCalendarScaleY(19) + x[3]) + Padding_Top_Bottom, Padding_Left_Right, 0);
        LL.requestLayout();
        break;
    }

    case 20: {
        // 8 pm
        p.setMargins(x[2] + Padding_Left_Right, dpToPx(GetCalendarScaleY(20) + x[3]) + Padding_Top_Bottom, Padding_Left_Right, 0);
        LL.requestLayout();
        break;
    }

    case 21: {
        // 9 pm
        p.setMargins(x[2] + Padding_Left_Right, dpToPx(GetCalendarScaleY(21) + x[3]) + Padding_Top_Bottom, Padding_Left_Right, 0);
        LL.requestLayout();
        break;
    }

    case 22: {
        // 10 pm
        p.setMargins(x[2] + Padding_Left_Right, dpToPx(GetCalendarScaleY(22) + x[3]) + Padding_Top_Bottom, Padding_Left_Right, 0);
        LL.requestLayout();
        break;
    }
    case 23: {
        // 11 pm
        p.setMargins(x[2] + Padding_Left_Right, dpToPx(GetCalendarScaleY(23) + x[3]) + Padding_Top_Bottom, Padding_Left_Right, 0);
        LL.requestLayout();
        break;
    }

    }

}

private int dpToPx(int dp) {
    if(_activity != null)
    {
            DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = _activity.getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
            int px = 0;
            if(displayMetrics != null)
            {
                px = Math.round((float) dp * ((float)displayMetrics.densityDpi / (float)DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_DEFAULT));

             return px;
            }
    }
            return 0;
        }

private int GetCalendarScaleY(int Time) {

    //Coordinates of Rows (Y Axis with respect to hours)
    int x = 0;

    switch (Time) {
    case 0: {
        // 12 am
        x = 0;
        break;
    }

    case 1: {
        // 1 am
        x = 80;
        break;
    }

    case 2: {
        // 2 am
        x = 160;
        break;
    }

    case 3: {
        // 3 am
        x = 240;
        break;
    }

    case 4: {
        // 4 am
        x = 320;
        break;
    }

    case 5: {
        // 5 am
        x = 400;
        break;
    }

    case 6: {
        // 6 am
        x = 480;
        break;
    }

    case 7: {
        // 7 am
        x = 560;
        break;
    }

    case 8: {
        // 8 am
        x = 640;
        break;
    }

    case 9: {
        // 9 am
        x = 720;
        break;
    }

    case 10: {
        // 10 am
        x = 800;
        break;
    }

    case 11: {
        // 11 am
        x = 880;
        break;
    }

    case 12: {
        // 12 pm
        x = 960;
        break;
    }

    case 13: {
        // 1 pm
        x = 1040;
        break;
    }

    case 14: {
        // 2 pm
        x = 1120;
        break;
    }

    case 15: {
        // 3 pm
        x = 1200;
        break;
    }

    case 16: {
        // 4 pm
        x = 1280;
        break;
    }

    case 17: {
        // 5 pm
        x = 1360;
        break;
    }

    case 18: {
        // 6 pm
        x = 1440;
        break;
    }

    case 19: {
        // 7 pm
        x = 1520;
        break;
    }

    case 20: {
        // 8 pm
        x = 1600;
        break;
    }

    case 21: {
        // 9 pm
        x = 1680;
        break;
    }

    case 22: {
        // 10 pm
        x = 1760;
        break;
    }
    case 23: {
        // 11 pm
        x = 1840;
        break;
    }

    }

    return x;
}
```